# SharePoint Online + Task List + Sync to Outlook

Tags: sharepoint, outlook-2013

I created a task list and selected "Sync to Outlook".

- From SharePoint Online i create a new task and assign it to me. After a while, the task appears in my Outlook, under the group "Team site : Tasks".
- From Outlook i rename the task and after a while the new name appears in the SharePoint task list.
- From Outlook i create a new task inside the group "Team site : Tasks" . **The task never appears in the SharePoint task list. Instead, it appears as Personal Task in "My Tasks"**.

Looks like the synchronized task list in Outlook is read-edit but not add. Is this true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

synchronized task list in Outlook also allows for adding and deleting of tasks which reflect in your sharepoint Tasks List. Follow the below steps to check this:-

1. Go To **Other Tasks**
2. Click on **Team site : Tasks**
3. on the Top of the window you are using to edit the items, you can see an option **Click Here To Add A New Task**. Double-click on it.
4. Fill the required details and click **Save & Close**
5. Go to your sharePoint Tasks List and refresh the page to see the changes.

If you do not get the newly added task in your list..Try the following step:-

1. **Go to Send/Receive** tab in the outlook ribbon and **click Update Folder**. If you are asked for credentials of your sharepoint login, please provide them.

It worked for me..I hope it works for you too. Let me know if you face any further issue :)